# Storyboard viewcontroller is opening?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uialertview, segue

When i click my login button i want to open home viewcontroller in my app,but just before somedays its working but now its not working ,when i click login it send the user details to server and give one server output .from this out put if it is "login" then i want move to home viewcontroller .Iam using Preforsegue method for next viewcontroller  my viewcontroller id is "App" and segue id is also "App".  this is the code i used to move to next viewcontroller at login.now this is not working..

inside login button :this after sending url with post method..then following code will execute

```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
  NSString * serverOutput= [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@",serverOutput);

        if(serverOutput!=NULL)
              {

                if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"login"])
                     {
                           [self getDetails];
                           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"App" sender:self];
                       }

 if(App)
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"App" sender:self];
  [_alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

       }
     } ];
     _alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait..."
                                        message:@"\n"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5);
[alertView addSubview:loading];

[spinner startAnimating];
[alertView show];
```

The value of "App" will be yes when i execute [self Detail] method

Comment: What is App in  if(App) and did you print serverOutput.

Comment: its segue name ,if that if(App) is success the goto segue

Comment: server output is login

Comment: What is the problem? It crashes? It doesn't perform the segue?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in if(App), check the value of App and see if the control is coming there ?

Comment: yes,it not perform segue  but that line is executing...means if(App) is true

Answer (score 0):

try giving a different id to segue and view controller. Clearly, you must have made some changes in the app somewhere and forgotten about it. Check the storyboard connection also. Try deleting the segue and given it again.